# How to replicate tee behavior in Python when using subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stderr, tee

I'm looking for a Python solution that will allow me to save the output of a command in a file without hiding it from the console.

FYI: I'm asking about [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) (as the Unix command line utility) and not the function with the same name from Python intertools module.

#### Details

- Python solution (not calling `tee`, it is not available under Windows)
- I do not need to provide any input to stdin for called process
- I have no control over the called program. All I know is that it will output something to stdout and stderr and return with an exit code.
- To work when calling external programs (subprocess)
- To work for both `stderr` and `stdout`
- Being able to differentiate between stdout and stderr because I may want to display only one of the to the console or I could try to output stderr using a different color - this means that `stderr = subprocess.STDOUT` will not work.
- Live output (progressive) - the process can run for a long time, and I'm not able to wait for it to finish.
- Python 3 compatible code (important)

#### References

Here are some incomplete solutions I found so far:

- http://devlishgenius.blogspot.com/2008/10/logging-in-real-time-in-python.html (mkfifo works only on Unix)
- http://blog.kagesenshi.org/2008/02/teeing-python-subprocesspopen-output.html (doesn't work at all)

[Diagram http://blog.i18n.ro/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Drawing_tee_py.png](http://blog.i18n.ro/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Drawing_tee_py.png)

#### Current code (second try)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function

import sys, os, time, subprocess, io, threading
cmd = "python -E test_output.py"

from threading import Thread
class StreamThread ( Thread ):
    def __init__(self, buffer):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.buffer = buffer
    def run ( self ):
        while 1:
            line = self.buffer.readline()
            print(line,end="")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            if line == '':
                break

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdoutThread = StreamThread(io.TextIOWrapper(proc.stdout))
stderrThread = StreamThread(io.TextIOWrapper(proc.stderr))
stdoutThread.start()
stderrThread.start()
proc.communicate()
stdoutThread.join()
stderrThread.join()

print("--done--")

#### test_output.py ####

#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, os, time

for i in range(0, 10):
    if i%2:
        print("stderr %s" % i, file=sys.stderr)
    else:
        print("stdout %s" % i, file=sys.stdout)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Real output

```
stderr 1
stdout 0
stderr 3
stdout 2
stderr 5
stdout 4
stderr 7
stdout 6
stderr 9
stdout 8
--done--
```

Expected output was to have the lines ordered. Remark, modifying the Popen to use only one PIPE is not allowed because in the real life I will want to do different things with stderr and stdout.

Also even in the second case I was not able to obtain real-time like out, in fact all the results were received when the process finished. By default, Popen should use no buffers (bufsize=0).

Comment: related: [Python subprocess get children's output to file and terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4984428/4279)

Comment: related: [Subprocess.Popen: cloning stdout and stderr both to terminal and variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17190221/4279)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Popen: Write to stdout AND log file simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535240/python-popen-write-to-stdout-and-log-file-simultaneously) Voting this way because this is a community wiki :-)

Answer (score 14):

If requiring python 3.6 isn't an issue there is now a way of doing this using `asyncio`. This method allows you to capture stdout and stderr separately but still have both stream to the tty without using threads. Here's a rough outline:

```
class RunOutput:
    def __init__(self, returncode, stdout, stderr):
        self.returncode = returncode
        self.stdout = stdout
        self.stderr = stderr


async def _read_stream(stream, callback):
    while True:
        line = await stream.readline()
        if line:
            callback(line)
        else:
            break


async def _stream_subprocess(cmd, stdin=None, quiet=False, echo=False) -> RunOutput:
    if isWindows():
        platform_settings = {"env": os.environ}
    else:
        platform_settings = {"executable": "/bin/bash"}
    if echo:
        print(cmd)
    p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        cmd,
        stdin=stdin,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        **platform_settings
    )
    out = []
    err = []

    def tee(line, sink, pipe, label=""):
        line = line.decode("utf-8").rstrip()
        sink.append(line)
        if not quiet:
            print(label, line, file=pipe)

    await asyncio.wait(
        [
            _read_stream(p.stdout, lambda l: tee(l, out, sys.stdout)),
            _read_stream(p.stderr, lambda l: tee(l, err, sys.stderr, label="ERR:")),
        ]
    )

    return RunOutput(await p.wait(), out, err)


def run(cmd, stdin=None, quiet=False, echo=False) -> RunOutput:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(
        _stream_subprocess(cmd, stdin=stdin, quiet=quiet, echo=echo)
    )

    return result
```

The code above was based on this blog post: https://kevinmccarthy.org/2016/07/25/streaming-subprocess-stdin-and-stdout-with-asyncio-in-python/

Comment: I got `TypeError: Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.` on `await asyncio.wait` when I ran this with Python 3.11.6.

Answer (score 12):

I see that this is a rather old post but just in case someone is still searching for a way to do this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "localhost"], 
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

with open("logfile.txt", "w") as log_file:
  while proc.poll() is None:
     line = proc.stderr.readline()
     if line:
        print "err: " + line.strip()
        log_file.write(line)
     line = proc.stdout.readline()
     if line:
        print "out: " + line.strip()
        log_file.write(line)
```

Comment: This worked for me, though I found `stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()` easier to use.

Comment: -1: This solution leads to a deadlock for any subprocess that can generate enough output on stdout or stderr and where stdout/stderr are not perfectly in sync.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: True, but you can workaround that problem by replacing `readline()` with `readline(size)`.  I have done something similar in other languages.  Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.readline

Comment: @kevinarpe wrong. `readline(size)` won't fix the deadlock. stdout/stderr should be read concurrently. See links under the question that show solutions using threads or asyncio.

Comment: @J.F.SebastianDoes this problem exist if I'm only interested in reading one of the streams?

Comment: @ThorSummoner: naturally, there is no issue if only [one stream is redirected to a pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279).

Comment: Is this really guaranteed not to miss any piped `stdout`? Let's say `proc` produces two final lines to stdout within the time frame of two subsequent `proc.poll()` calls: **1.** `proc.poll() == None` -> read single line -> one more line exists in `stdout` but process is finished -> **2.** `proc.poll() == returncode` and the `while` loop breaks (while there is still remaining lines in `stdout`). Also, consider setting `stderr` to `subprocess.STDOUT` to avoid deadlocks.

Answer (score 8):

This is a straightforward port of [`tee(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) to Python.

```py
import sys

sinks = sys.argv[1:]
sinks = [open(sink, "w") for sink in sinks]
sinks.append(sys.stderr)
while True:
    input = sys.stdin.read(1024)
    if input:
        for sink in sinks:
            sink.write(input)
    else:
        break
```

I'm running on Linux right now but this ought to work on most platforms.

---

Now for the `subprocess` part, I don't know how you want to 'wire' the subprocess's `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` to your `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` and file sinks, but I know you can do this:

```py
import subprocess

callee = subprocess.Popen(
    ["python", "-i"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
```

Now you can access [`callee.stdin`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin), [`callee.stdout`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) and [`callee.stderr`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr) like normal files, enabling the above "solution" to work. If you want to get the [`callee.returncode`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode), you'll need to make an extra call to [`callee.poll()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll).

Be careful with writing to `callee.stdin`: if the process has exited when you do that, an error may be rised (on Linux, I get `IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`).

Comment: This is suboptimal in Linux, since Linux provides an ad-hoc [`tee(f_in, f_out, len, flags)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/tee) API, but that's not the point right?

Comment: I updated the question, the problem is that I was not able to find how to use subprocess in order to get the data from the two pipes gradually and not all at once at the end of the process.

Comment: I know that your code should work but there is a small requirement that does break the entire logic: I want to be able to distinguish between stdout and stderr and this means that I have to read from both of them but I do not know which will get new data. Please take a look at the example code.

Comment: @Sorin, that means you'll have to either use two threads. One reads on `stdout`, one reads on `stderr`. If you are going to write both to the same file, you can acquire a lock on the sinks when you start reading and release it after writing a line terminator. :/

Comment: Using threads for this does not sounds too appealing to me, maybe we'll find something else. It's strange that this is a common issue but nobody provided a complete solution for it.

Comment: @badp I tried the threads a approach but it doesn't work. I updates the question to include the new example.

Comment: @Sorin The output you have posted _is_ ordered. You had `line1 line3 line5 line7 line9` on stderr, `line0 line2 line4 line6 line8` on stdout. Sure, in that run the `stderr` thread happened to get output first, which meant you had `line1 line0 line3 line2 line5 line4...` instead of `line0 line1 line2 line3 line4 line5...` -- but you didn't get `line0 line3 line5 line1 line2...` or `line4 line2 line1 line0 line6...` or `line0 liline1 line3 linne2 line3e5...`. I'm afraid that for a program that has to accept arbitrary input this kind of nondeterminism is unaivoidable if not even necessary.

Answer (score 6):

This is how it can be done

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with open('log.log', 'w') as log:
    proc = Popen(["ping", "google.com"], stdout=PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
    while proc.poll() is None:
        text = proc.stdout.readline() 
        log.write(text)
        sys.stdout.write(text)
```

Comment: For anyone who's wondering, YES you can use `print()` instead of `sys.stdout.write()`. :-)

Comment: @progyammer `print` will add an extra newline which is not what you want when you need to faithfully reproduce the output.

Comment: Yes but `print(line, end='')` could solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

Based on the community wiki answer, here is an updated version.

- Added types
- Use `gather` instead of `wait` (`wait` gives a warning)
- Don't unnecessarily decode to `str`
- Add timeout.

This is a complete file that you can run; the timeout is set to 5 seconds so it should time out.

***NOTE: Python buffers stdout by default so you need to use `-u` everywhere.***

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S python3 -u

import asyncio
from typing import BinaryIO, Callable, Union
import sys

class RunOutput:
    def __init__(self, exit_code: int, stdout: list[bytes], stderr: list[bytes]):
        self.exit_code = exit_code
        self.stdout = stdout
        self.stderr = stderr


async def _read_stream(stream: asyncio.StreamReader, callback: Callable[[bytes], None]):
    while True:
        line = await stream.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break
        callback(line)


async def _stream_subprocess(command: list[str]) -> RunOutput:
    p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *command,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    stdout: list[bytes] = []
    stderr: list[bytes] = []

    def tee(line: bytes, sink: list[bytes], out: BinaryIO):
        sink.append(line)
        out.write(line)

    assert p.stdout is not None
    assert p.stderr is not None

    await asyncio.gather(
        _read_stream(p.stdout, lambda l: tee(l, stdout, sys.stdout.buffer)),
        _read_stream(p.stderr, lambda l: tee(l, stderr, sys.stderr.buffer)),
    )

    exit_code = await p.wait()

    return RunOutput(exit_code, stdout, stderr)


def run(command: list[str], timeout: Union[int, float, None]) -> RunOutput:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(
        asyncio.wait_for(_stream_subprocess(command), timeout)
    )


def main():
    if "--count" in sys.argv:
        import time

        for i in range(10):
            print(f"A stdout {i}")
            print(f"B stderr {i}", file=sys.stderr)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f"C stderr {i}", file=sys.stderr)
            print(f"D stdout {i}")
            time.sleep(1)
    else:
        run(["python3", "-u", __file__, "--", "--count"], 5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a simple example using `tee` (I'll show you can do this without `tee` later) you can do the following:

```py
def tee(command, **kwargs):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, **kwargs)
    t_out = subprocess.Popen(['tee', '-a', '/dev/stderr'], stdin=p.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    t_err = subprocess.Popen(['tee', '-a', '/dev/stderr'], stdin=p.stderr, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    return p, t_out, t_err
```

Here:

1. Start our command in a subprocess, `p`, capturing both `stderr` and `stdout`.
2. We start another subprocess, `t_out`, running `tee`, and we capture only `stderr` (allowing stdout to flow out from `tee` normally)
3. We do the same for the subprocess `t_err`, but sending `stderr` from `p` and capturing only `stdout` (allowing `stderr` to flow normally to stderr)

The end result is that stdout and stderr of your command are output to the terminal normally and also captured in the returned subprocesses.

Suppose a simple program that writes to stderr and stdout:

```py
# test.py
import sys, time
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i, file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
    else:
        print(i, flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

You could do:

```py
print('starting')
process, t_out, t_err = tee([sys.executable, 'test.py'])
while process.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.1)  # wait for process to finish
print('done')
print('stdout:', t_out.stderr.read())
print('stderr:', t_err.stdout.read())
```

In addition to the program's output, you can see that stdout and stderr are readable by the Python script:

```
starting
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
done
stdout: 1
3
5
7
9

stderr: 0
2
4
6
8
```

## Without using `tee`

Note that use of the program `tee` is not actually necessary. This could just as easily be a pure python program that reads stdin and tees the output the same as `tee` does.

For example, the following Python script can be used instead. All it does is read stdin and print it to stdout and stderr.

```
# tee.py
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line, file=sys.stdout, flush=True, end='')
    print(line, file=sys.stderr, flush=True, end='')
```

Then the first example can be modified like this:

```py
def tee(command, **kwargs):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, **kwargs)
    t_out = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'tee.py'], stdin=p.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    t_err = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'tee.py'], stdin=p.stderr, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    return p, t_out, t_err
```

The end result is similar to the first example, but doesn't require the program `tee`.

---

This solution also doesn't necessarily require the use of the additional subprocesses. It's just one way to do it. The same solution could be done in two threads that consume stderr/stdout of the first subprocess.

CAVEAT: some substantial changes would be needed to guarantee correct order of arrival of messages to the terminal if stdout and stderr are written to at about the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to interact with the process you can use the subprocess module just fine.

Example:

tester.py

```
import os
import sys

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    print file

sys.stderr.write("Oh noes, a shrubbery!")
sys.stderr.flush()
sys.stderr.close()
```

testing.py

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'tester.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print stdout, stderr
```

In your situation you can simply write stdout/stderr to a file first. You can send arguments to your process with communicate as well, though I wasn't able to figure out how to continually interact with the subprocess.

Comment: This doesn't show you error messages in STDERR in context of STDOUT, which can make debugging shell-scripts etc nearly impossible.

Comment: Meaning...? In this script anything delivered through STDERR is printed to the screen along with STDOUT. If you're referring to return codes, just use `p.poll()` to retrieve them.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the "progressive" condition.

Answer (score -1):

On Linux, if you really need something like the [`tee(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tee.2.html) syscall, you can get it like this:

```
import os
import ctypes

ld = ctypes.CDLL(None, use_errno=True)

SPLICE_F_NONBLOCK = 0x02


def tee(fd_in, fd_out, length, flags=SPLICE_F_NONBLOCK):
    result = ld.tee(
        ctypes.c_int(fd_in),
        ctypes.c_int(fd_out),
        ctypes.c_size_t(length),
        ctypes.c_uint(flags),
    )

    if result == -1:
        errno = ctypes.get_errno()
        raise OSError(errno, os.strerror(errno))

    return result
```

To use this, you probably want to use Python 3.10 and something with `os.splice` (or use `ctypes` in the same way to get `splice`). See the [`tee(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tee.2.html) for an example.

Answer (score -2):

My solution isn't elegant, but it works.

You can use powershell to gain access to "tee" under WinOS.

```
import subprocess
import sys

cmd = ['powershell', 'ping', 'google.com', '|', 'tee', '-a', 'log.txt']

if 'darwin' in sys.platform:
    cmd.remove('powershell')

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
p.wait()
```

Comment: Gives an invalid command line error message from `ping` in MacOS.