# How to redirect python output to both python console and a text file in Windows

Tags: python, windows, logging, cmd

I have a python script_1 which will be used to call another python script_2 using subprocess. When I do that I can see so many print statements and ouputs on the python console (or cmd). How can I redirect this output to a file along with displaying the output on the python console.

Basically, I need a windows executable command for `' | & tee '` command of Linux.
I tried many methods and all those didn't work.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Pure python solution: use the `logging` package with two handlers (one logging to stderr and one logging to file).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Popen: Write to stdout AND log file simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535240/python-popen-write-to-stdout-and-log-file-simultaneously)

Comment: The easiest way in `cmd` might be `{your python command line} > file.log & type file.log`, although this will display the text only after your scripts have finished execution, of course...