# duplicating output from subprocess popen so it would print and also save into PIPE?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, pipe, stdout

I want to run a `subprocess.Popen('echo 1; sleep 1; echo 1', shell=True, stdout=?)` in a way I would have the output appear (at run time) and also be able to save it into a PIPE or file.

So far I ran with `proc = subprocess.Popen('echo 1; sleep 1; echo 1', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)` giving me the 2nd requirement, and then I would print the result of `out, err = proc.communicate()`, but using `communicate` is blocking, and so, if the `Popen` takes a long time, I can't show the output and that's unacceptable.

Can I somehow leave the `stdout=` field empty (to enable console output) and also copy output to a PIPE?

**Update**. This is not the same as **[Python Popen: Write to stdout AND log file simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535240/python-popen-write-to-stdout-and-log-file-simultaneously)** because I want to be able to access the oputput during the run, and the solution there suggests accessing proc.stdout which is blocking until the end of the run.

Comment: I don't understand `communicate` is blocking ? What is it blocking?

Comment: In [4]: subprocess.Popen.communicate?
Signature: subprocess.Popen.communicate(self, input=None)
Docstring:
Interact with process: Send data to stdin.  Read data from
stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.  **Wait for
process to terminate**.  The optional input argument should be a
string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data
should be sent to the child.

communicate() returns a tuple (stdout, stderr).

Comment: @CIsForCookies If the duplicate doesn't answer your question, then what are you trying to do? If you don't want to block when reading stdout, then how do you want to read it? Reading `stdout` doesn't force you to wait for the process completion - you can pause/stop at any newline.

Comment: How can I read stdout? the only way I found was `for line in proc.stdout` which will block until proc has finished...