# How to print an output a new console opened using subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to achieve a functionality where I can open a new command prompt and run some batch commands. Then redirecting the output to a `logfile` and `console` on real time. So I am using `wtee.exe` (ex command: `dir 2 >& 1 | wtee.exe logFile.txt`). Choosing `popen` over `os.system` because I need control over the new process (new command prompt) As I wont be able to use pipe symbol in Popen. I did the below functionality `newConsole = Popen( ['cmd','/V:ON /K dir 2>&1'], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT ) outputLog = Popen( [wtee.exe,'logFile.txt'], stdin=newConsole.stdout, )` I can see the log file is generated and also the output in command prompt (on main window and not in new console). How can I print an output a new console opened using subprocess?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Popen: Write to stdout AND log file simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535240/python-popen-write-to-stdout-and-log-file-simultaneously)