# Python subprocess exhibits different behavior in command line and GUI console while streaming ouput

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am using subprocess of python27 lib to run a big python file(execute.py) from another python file(sample.py).

If I run the sample.py (which has subprocess statements) in windows command line,it is running properly and streaming the live output well.

But in the python GUI console,when I run the GUI python file(has same subprocess statements) the GUI window is Not responding for some minutes after some time the output is printing as whole(not streaming).

Here is the snippet:

```
cmdlist = ["python", "execute.py","name","xyz"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdlist, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ""):
        self.output.write(line)

self.output.write("\n Finished process\n")
```

Hitting my head for a week and could not find any solution so far.

Comment: The GUI might store the entire output in a buffer before printing it out. What exactly do you mean by Python GUI console?

Comment: My python GUI is attached with console in it.There we can see the output of any runs.Should I need to set `bufsize` in subprocess for live output?

Comment: What python GUI are you using?

Comment: I am using wxpython for GUI

Comment: Wait a second.. "I run the sample.py [..] in windows command." "in the python GUI console,when I run the GUI python file" - do you run *different* code in the GUI? If so, please list the *differences*.

Comment: Subprocess statements are same in both sample.py and GUI python file.In GUI python file those statements are in a function.

Comment: What about `self.output`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116674/discussion-between-nithya-and-mistermiyagi).

Comment: I didnt get you.are you asking me to explain self.ouput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run script in command line: the output will send directly to the terminal. 
The Python GUI console(IDLE) base on tkinter tool kit so when you run the script:
the output will send to the buffer. The GUI tool take a bit of time to show the buffer to screen. Therefore the time to show the output will be longer when running with command line. If your script print too much, the buffer will be overflow then the "Not responding" occurs.

Comment: Nice catch,then how can I fix this? any idea?I need the same way like in windows command line.

Comment: is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do not set `stdout` or `stderr` if you want them to go to an outer (controlling) process.

```
cmdlist = ["python", "execute.py","name","xyz"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdlist)
# do other stuff here if you like
self.output.write(
  "\n Finished process (%s)\n" % proc.wait()  # wait until process has finished; process will stream to stdout/stderr while we wait
)
```

If you set `stdout` or `stderr` to `subprocess.PIPE` your current (python) process creates a *new* pipe by which it communicates with the subprocess. Basically, your own process will buffer the subprocess' output.

Even if you don't explicitly buffer anything, python itself will do some buffering. This especially applies when you redirect `stderr` and write it to your own `stdout` - stdout is buffered by default, while stderr would not have been. Many programs also write to *the same line* and reset the cursor, thus doing `proc.stdout.readline()` will buffer, waiting for the line to finish.

Now, if you don't set `stdout` and `stderr`, the subprocess will *inherit* your `stdout` and `stderr`. This means it can write *directly* to the outer, controlling process.

Comment: It is throwing Attribute error.`
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readline' `    the file is running in the background(thread)

Comment: @Nithya My bad. Of Course, you cannot do `proc.stdout.redline` when not redirecting `stdout`, since `proc.stdout` is not set then. I've fixed the corresponding section.

Comment: still can i  use the for loop in the `# do other stuff` section?

Comment: @Nithya You cannot use `proc.stdout`, if that's what you mean. Are you attempting to `[tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command))? If so, look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2997533/5349916). Basically, you have to use `proc.stdout.read` instead of `proc.stdout.readline`.

Comment: No.Not `tee`.I am trying to display the live output in wxpython GUI window.

Comment: @Nithya I get that. The question is whether you *also* need the output in your python application or not.

Comment: Partially correct.The output is printing in python application.The problem is  while running the script the application window went to not responding state and the output is not streaming as live instead it is printed as whole.I nee it to live streaming as in windows command