# Can I redirect my print statements to multiple outputs without modifying my whole code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, sys

I know that I can redirect print statements to a file:
import sys
sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w")

But I need to print to my terminal in the meanwhile. The idea was to write to print statements for each print. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Have you considered using [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)? Might look more complicated than simply using `print` at first and might be overkill for very small, simple scripts, but it supports multiple targets (i.e. handlers).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this answer: [How to redirect python subprocess stderr and stdout to multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283595/how-to-redirect-python-subprocess-stderr-and-stdout-to-multiple-files)

The basic idea is to create a multi-output file-type object and assign it to `sys.stdout`.

```
import sys

class MultiOut(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.handles = args

    def write(self, s):
        for f in self.handles:
            f.write(s)

with open('q1', 'w') as f1, open('q2', 'w') as f2, open('q3', 'w') as f3:
    # add all the files (including sys.stdout) to which the output should be written
    sys.stdout = MultiOut(f1, f2, sys.stdout)
    for i, c in enumerate('abcde'):
        print(c, 'out')
        print(i, 'err')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can redirect your code to as many files as you wish as well as to  the CLI at the same time. There is a need to introduce a new class to override the existing write method.
Try the following snippet, it works for me:

```
import sys

class MultiPrinter(object):
    def __init__(self, *targets):
        self.targets = targets
    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.targets:
            f.write(obj)
            f.flush()

f = open('logs.txt', 'w')
f1 = open('logs1.txt', 'w')
f2 = open('logs2.txt', 'w')
sys_org = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = MultiPrinter(sys_org, f, f1, f2)
print('First Statement.....')
print('Another Statement....')
```