# Output everything (input and output) to a text file in Python

Tags: python, output

I have a pretty big script and I need to output what the user typed in, and what the response of the program was. Trouble is my big file.

```
import subprocess    

with open("output.txt", "wb") as f:

    subprocess.check_call(["python", "trouble.py"], stdout=f)
```

The following code works fine except it doesn't display anything from trouble.py on my command prompt but it still writes to output.txt.

```
import troube
```

When I add this, the program runs correctly (runs as if I was just running the file normally) but doesn't output anything.

How do I go about doing this? 
Thanks

Comment: Well it seems like you have redirected stdout to the file, so it does not print anything on terminal

Comment: subprocess.check_call(["python", "trouble.py"])
Should I remove the other parameter?

Comment: anyone else can help? really need this done

Comment: Is it a hard requirement to create the log of the session from a python program? If not, it would likely be easier to just use the `script` command.

Comment: I don't have any experience with `subprocess` , but giving a very quick look to the documentation I could suggest to try `subprocess.check_call(["python", "trouble.py"], stdout=f,shell=True)` . I don't know exactly what this does though (I couldn't find it).

Comment: No sure, but search "Tee". For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996887/how-to-replicate-tee-behavior-in-python-when-using-subprocess