# Process stdout or stderr redirected to files during subprocess.check_call

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I have this code

```
fd_log_out = open(path_log_out, 'w')
fd_log_err = open(path_log_err, 'w')
subprocess.check_call(command, cwd=path, stdout=fd_log_out, stderr=fd_log_err)
```

I would like to process the stderr during the check_call to trigger an event if something is seen. I have tried to create a subclass of **TextIOWrapper** and overwrite the **write** function but it was never called.

What is the called function by subprocess.check_call. The source code is too complex to find it.

Is there any other way to do this? With PIPE maybe ?

Thanks.

Comment: The whole point of a redirection is that it's changing where a FD writes to. If you pass an object that has a FD number (that is, where it has a `fileno()` method) as `stdout` or `stderr`, the output from the process goes *straight* to that FD -- the Python interpreter never sees it at all, and has no opportunity to process it.

Comment: The idea was to analyse lines of a wrtie call, check, call super.write.

Comment: As I said, it's bypassing the interpreter at an OS level; the data isn't exposed to Python at all. (Which is to say, yes, you'd need to use `subprocess.PIPE` to implement a shim).

Comment: Related:  [How to replicate tee behavior in Python when using subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2996887/674039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an object with a `fileno()` method is passed as an argument to `stdout=` or `stderr=` of `subprocess.Popen()`, then the relevant file descriptor is redirected with `fdup2()` or a similar syscall.

This means the data is sent *directly* from the subprocess to the file associated with the FD -- it isn't read by the Python interpreter at all, so the Python interpreter never calls `write()` on an associated object.

To work around this, you do indeed need to use `subprocess.PIPE` -- and then have an ongoing process shuffling data on *both* `stdout` and `stderr` (you can't do it one-after-the-other without causing deadlocks) through analysis and to their eventual destinations.