# How to return Ansible ` PLAY RECAP` data to Python caller?

Tags: python, ansible

I'm calling my Ansible playbook from a Python script.

```python
subprocess.call("ansible-playbook -i hosts my_playbook.yml", shell=True)
```

When this completes there is a `PLAY RECAP` which includes a list of targets and if any tasks for that target `failed` or were `unreachable`.

```yaml
PLAY RECAP 
****************************************************************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=21   changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

What I'd like to do is something like ...

```python
ansible_return_data = subprocess.call("ansible-playbook -i hosts my_playbook.yml", shell=True) 

for target in ansible_return_data:
    if target["failed"] > 0:
        python.do_stuff()
```

So my question is, how is the `PLAY RECAP` data returned to Python and how would I access it?

Comment: I use the same subprocces and i use it like this : `runner = subprocess.Popen(["ansible-playbook",  "create.yml"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` and then i do : `stdout, stderr = runner.communicate()` and it give the output, which then you need to use python regex to filter

Comment: @BatchenRegev awesome. I wish it preserved color encoding though. I can't find a way to TEE instead of PIPE.

Comment: For "_I can't find a way to `TEE` instead of `PIPE`_" you may have a look into [How to replicate `tee` behavior in Python when using `subprocess`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996887/) or [How to write to `stdout` AND to log file simultaneously with `Popen`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535240/) ...