# Print function of python prints the result when the script ends inside of printing when the line is executed in gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab, subprocess, gitlab-ci

The print function of python prints the output at the end, when the script ends.

```
build_call = subprocess.Popen(build_unit_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
build_call.wait()
out, err = build_call.communicate()
print(out)
```

I have multiple such print functions. Every print is done when the script is about to end. Is there any way python prints as soon as its execution completes?

Comment: How are you running the script? If its output is to a file or pipe, it's buffered by default. Use `print(out, flush=True)` to flush immediately.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent your `print` statements from being buffered, set the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` to 1

In your .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
variables:
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED: "1"
```

This will force the stdout/street streams to be unbuffered and allow messages to be printed out immediately.

---

The other thing happening here is that your subprocess call is capturing output, so you're only printing out the output *after* each command. To avoid this, see: [How to replicate tee behavior in Python when using subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2996887/5747944)