# Python subprocess not printing live live log

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, subprocess

We have issue with python not printing live log on Jenkins console.

Here is the code we are using.

```
def runCommand(cmd, shellval="True"):
    print('Command is: {0}'.format(cmd))
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=shellval, universal_newlines=True)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    out, err = p.communicate()
    return p.returncode, out, err
```

To fix live printing I am using this code. We also have requirement to return output from the function apart from printing live.

```
def runCommand(cmd, shellval="True"):
    print('Command is 19: {0}'.format(cmd))
    with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=shellval,
                         universal_newlines=True ) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            print(line, end='')
        out = p.stdout
        err = p.stderr
        rc_code = p.returncode
    return rc_code, out, err`
```

Above code solves the problem but out variable is not text and getting below error to print.

`<_io.TextIOWrapper name=7 encoding='UTF-8'>`

Alternative option tried is :

```
def runCommand(cmd, shellval="True"):
    print('Command is 21: {0}'.format(cmd))
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=shellval,
                         universal_newlines=True )
    with p as cp:
        for line in cp.stdout:
            print(line, end='')
    out, err = p.communicate()
    rc_code = p.returncode
    return rc_code, out, err
```

Above code block give this error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

We also have PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true ENV variable set.

Any pointer to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replicate tee behavior in Python when using subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996887/how-to-replicate-tee-behavior-in-python-when-using-subprocess)